# AWS e RDS Data Access Layer for Business Partner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, data-access-layer

I need some special use case, and I cannot image how resolve this. I need to enable access to my database (or a backup) to an external partner. 
I could backup the database and leave him to access, but I would keep some table private, for my business logic.

I tried to write a Lambda Function to copy each night my DB, and leave the parter access in just-read mode, but this solution serve to the partner the whole DB.

Some ideas? Sorry for the inaccurate question.

Comment: you can create a specific user and grant privilege to specific tables.

Comment: @dassum using IAM role? or other?

Comment: You need to create a user with speicific privileges at the database level, not an IAM Role since your partner is not going to interact with Aws ressources.

Answer (score 0):

Does your database have public IP to allow access from outside? If it does, you can create a user inside your database allowing access to the specific databases, then you send the database public IP, the user and the password to your partner.

If your database doesn't have public IP, you can create an EC2 instance within the same VPC and attach a public IP to it (avoiding exposing your database to the world), your partner will need to ssh in this EC2 instance and use the user and password with limited access to only those databases you want him to see.

Hope it can give you some insights.